# Android app signing - valid alias names

Tags: android, cordova, code-signing

Keytool places very few constraints on what can be used in the store & key passwords and in the actual alias name. I have found only the following constraints

- The two passwords must have 6+ characters.  However, non-alphanumeric chars seem just fine. e.g. `j+*!%#` is an acceptable store password.
- The alias appears to have no constraints at all. Even a single character appears to be an acceptable alias. `+*`, for example does just fine as an alias.

What is not clear to  me is this - does Phonegap + the Android SDK accept such cryptic aliases and passwords and, later, will the alias be acceptable to the Google Play store?  I haven't found any definitive information on the subject and would much appreciate any help.

Comment: Silent downvoter could you care to explain why you did so?  Pretty arrow caught your attention, perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Play Store has no idea what alias is used to sign APKs, and cannot find out. You are free to use whatever alias you see fit.

The alias is only used locally by the Java keystore to identify a particular signing key. That information is not bundled with the APK after signing.